# Error in stateless observable service: Type 'Observable<Course[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm learning rxjs and I got stuck with this error.

I have the following method

```
  getCourseById(id: number): Observable<Course> {
    return this.http.get<Course[]>('the-api').pipe(
      map(courses =>
          courses.filter(course => course.id === id)
        )
    )
  }
```

I make a call to a particular API endpoint, grab the entire response, then use map to filter against that collection and get the course with id equals to the parameter id.

The function returns an Observable of type Course.

Yet, in the console I see:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Course[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'.
  Type 'Course[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Course': id, name, url, description

 27     return this.http.get<Course[]>('the-api').pipe(
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 28       map(courses =>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 30         )
    ~~~~~~~~~
 31     )
    ~~~~~
```

I don't know how to fix it.
I'd appreciate help.
Thanks

Comment: You tell `HttpClient` to get an array of `Course` items, have a method signature that indicates a single instance is the return, and you never transform the fetched array into a single `Course` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Array.find()` instead of `Array.filter()`. This will only return the matching object:

```
getCourseById(id: number): Observable<Course> {
    return this.http.get<Course[]>('the-api').pipe(
      map(courses =>
          courses.find(course => course.id === id)!
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tobias.
If I use filter() and take the first element with [0] works.
If I use find() as in your answer I receive another error.
Type 'Observable<Course | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'.
  Type 'Course | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Course'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Course'.

Comment: Yes, typescript doesnt know that the find method in your case will always finds something so it adds undefined as a possible return type. If you don't want that you can add a `!` after the find. This will force typescript to know that the result won't be undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tobias!